# NullPointerException from saving file to external storage (on one phone but not other)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-sdcard

Trying to save a file to storage, and on Samsung Galaxy S3 it works fine, but on HTC One S it crashes. I have a feeling maybe HTC One S does not have an external storage specified on the device. So the question is, how can I circumvent this?

Here are the three functions that makes it crash on the One S:

```
public void takePicture(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE, "SL_IMG_");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

private Uri getMediaFileUri(int type, String lift){
    return Uri.fromFile(getMediaFile(type, lift));
}

private File getMediaFile(int type, String lift){
    File dir;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        dir = new     File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "StrongLifts"); //set destination folder
    } else {
        dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES), "StrongLifts/" + lift); //set destination folder
    }
    if (!dir.exists()){ // if dir does not exist
        if (!dir.mkdirs()) {    // create dir
            // something went horribly wrong
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And the logcat message:

```
nullPointerException: file
at android.net.Uri.fromFile(Uri.java:441)
at no.whg.getfit.LogWorkout.getMediaFileUri(LogWorkout.java:202)
at no.whg.getfit.LogWorkout.takePicture... etc
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is on line 202 in LogWorkout.java?

Comment: `return Uri.fromFile(getMediaFile(type, lift));`

Comment: Please include more code as we don't know what's `lift`? How is it ending up null? You have necessary permissions? Is it actually writing to external storage?

Comment: `lift` is just something we use to define part of the filename, so for example if we save a video in the "deadlift" category, lift is deadlift. It ends up null because it can't save to file. And as stated, it works perfectly fine on for example Samsung Galaxy S3. But it's just that on HTC One S for example it crashes, so I'm guessing that phone does not have external storage, and so my question as stated is: is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: Have you checked the external storage state to see what it is? Maybe there is no external storage. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState()

Comment: I figured out the problem below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel quite dumb right now. I figured out what the problem was, when the phone is plugged in trough USB it mounts the sdcard on the phone, so automatically the phone would crash. But when I plugged it out everything worked fine, sorry for the inconvenience but hopefully someone else will have the same problem in the future :)

Comment: ? Am confused! how would plugging in the phone via usb would cause it to crash?

Comment: @t0mm13b external storage isn't available on the phone if its mounted via USB.

Comment: Interesting. TIL! Did not know that! In fairness, there should be a way to dis-ambiguate internal and external storage if no SDCard mechanism is in place (i.e. no hardware facility for sdcard - which is the trend happening now by OEMs)... I'll upvote your comment @Pedantic for that